# Why is Perl using LDAP?

Tags: oracle, perl, ldap

Amongst the stuff I have inherited in my current role is an ancient Perl CGI web application (circa 2002). The connects to an Oracle database. It appears to be using an equally ancient LDAP server to resolve the Oracle database. Formerly, everything here used the LDAP service to retrieve the TNS connection definition. We have migrated everything else to use a simpler DNS name based connection string. I want to do the same for the Perl code.

But I can't find any references to the LDAP server in the Perl code.

I can establish a direct correlation between an HTTP request being made (and hence the perl code executing) and a connection to the LDAP server.

Looking in the code, the DBI constructor looks like this:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Oracle:DB","username","password", {RaiseError => 1,AutoCommit => 1}) || die("Connecting to oracle");
```

(but with different literals for DB, username and password).

Clearly this is using a TNS definition, but I can't see how Perl knows to lookup the TNS definition in the LDAP service, nor any indication of where it should find the LDAP service.

I've looked through all the referenced Perl module files and can't see any reference to "LDAP" nor the LDAP host.

(but I did scan te entire filesystem for a tnsnames.ora file and didn't find one other than the sample file in the Oracle client install).

Where else should I be looking?

Comment: It's pretty hard to guess what's going on without seeing the codebase or system setup. Sometimes the thing asking for the credentials invokes LDAP for you (but could just as well ask Active Directory or whatever). Investigate how you get the user is my best shot in the dark.

Comment: Is there a sqlnet.ora file?  I'd expect your server has one with a `names.directory_path` setting that includes LDAP.  And then likely some `names.ldap_*` settings.

Comment: If you use LDAP server to resolve the alias then you don't need any `tnsnames.ora` file. Search your system for `sqlnet.ora`

Comment: According to DBD::Oracle, `DB` is either a SID or service name of a local database, a service named defined in a `TNSNAMES.ORA` file, or an EZCONNECT url of the form `//host[:port][/service_name]`. But that might not be exhaustive. See [this](https://serverfault.com/q/192359/129752)

Comment: @JustinCave Thank you for actually reading my question before commenting - and thank you again for pointing me in *exactly* the right direction. Problem solved. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that you'd find a `sqlnet.ora` file on the server that has a `names.directory_path` setting that includes LDAP.  Likely, there will be some `names.ldap_*` settings in that file as well.